# PHP Multiple File upload - some form variables omitted after selecting too many (large?) files?

Tags: php, forms, apache

I have a very basic PHP multiple file upload form:

```
<form action="file.upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['id']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="bypass" value="1" />
<input multiple type="file" name="file[]" id="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Everything works fine for a few files, but when I upload too many large files, the hidden variables are no longer posted to PHP (!)

I am not sure what is causing the from variables to be ignored by PHP (?)

(I've checked with fiddler and the form indeed sends the right data from clientside... i.e., form fields `bypass` and `id` are both properly populated on clientside...)

Comment: How many is too many? How large are they?

Comment: I think you should update `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in `php.ini`, note that `post_max_size` must be at least equal or greater then `upload_max_filesize`.

Comment: do you know if the `post_max_size` is the size of all the form fields, or just each individual file? also, is there a way to update these fields without using php.ini ?

Comment: `post_max_size` should be the sum of all files. Again, how many is too many? What kind of numbers are we talking about here?

Comment: less than 50 - iphone 5s image files. is there a solution other than to modify .ini?

Comment: you have to modify the `php.ini` because no PHP code is executed before all file handling is already finished by PHP. PHP has braindead API for `$_FILES`, `$_COOKIES`, `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` and you have to live with it.